# Core dump file appears then disappears

Tags: linux, coredump

I have a program with a fairly large memory footprint, about 30GB, that core dumps.

While the program is dumping (top showing it as D - Defunct) the dump file is visible and readable. It's in the expected directory, with the expected file name format. Everything is on local disk. I can even load the file in gdb. Obviously the dump takes a few minutes on a process this size.

The file gets up to about 13GB, then the process exits ... and the core file disappears! Poof.

Platform: Redhat EL6 (2.6.32-220.4.2.el6.x86_64)

The file system plenty of space, over 500GB free.

```
$ df .
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
blahblahblah         834006872 270024424 521617316  35% /data
```

ulimit isn't showing any applicable restrictions:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
<snipped>
```

Edit: Smaller core dumps don't disappear. Including for this same program. This seems to be specific to enormous core dumps.

```
tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
<snip>
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1020
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
<snip>
```

Comment: Do you have the source code of the program?

Comment: @Basile Not sure why that's relevant. Regardless, the source would be enormous.

Comment: Underhill, why not start the program under gdb and `run` or attach to it while it is running. When program got SIGSEGV, gdb will get it and you will be able to debug program without needs of saving the coredump.

Comment: Did you find the reason of this issue?

Comment: It appears the Redhat ABRT service was to blame.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using the ext2/ext3/ext4, you could be faced with a restriction on the maximum file size for your file system. [This page](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC) (warning: in Russian) tells that the **lower limit** for the range of valid values for a maximum file size in ext* file system equals to **16 GB** (the exact value depends on your drive's cluster size). Therefore we can not exclude the fact that you have gone beyond that limit.

There are plenty of tools that may help to find out which process had wiped your file: [lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof), [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), [auditd](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/). They all are supported in your kernel and they all are different, and it hard to say now which one of them will fit you best.

Comment: This is a possibility. The core file definitely went over 20GB.

Comment: @Underhill, If it's not a secret, what process consumes the memory so severe? Did you put some database entirely into the memory ?

Comment: "This page (warning: in Russian) tells", but there is still no references for 16GB limits on ext2,3,4.

Comment: @osgx, filesystem block size equal to 1 kB defines the limiting value for the maximum file size equal to 16GB (proof from some [blog](http://linuxfilesystems-ext2ext3ext4.datastoragedigest.com/), hope you'll trust them :)

Comment: spasibo, but I will trust sources.

Comment: @VitalyIsaev Yes, it's an in-memory database.

Comment: Block size seems to be 4K. Adding tune2fs info to question.